# Amadeus API Seatmap Coordinates

Tags: amadeus

Are the rules about Amadeus seatmaps conversion to another standard (say used by star alliance) documented somewhere ? We need to provide some seatmaps in the Amadeus format from another provider.

Comment: The Amadeus SeatMap Display API builds the seatmap of each aircraft based on IATA standard that provides a list of seats. You can check out more details in the video tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTOQjGsZLfI.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.